# Facebook Post image to Facebook fan page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

It's funny really...

This is my script

```
       var imgURL = "http://onseiekoerant.com/upload/uploads/1411504661_2786.jpg";
        FB.api('/'MY PAGE ID'/photos', 'post', { 
            message: 'Website Genius',
            url: imgURL,
            access_token: accessToken
        }, function (response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
            } else {
                alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                //alert('Post ID: ' + response.post_id);
            }
            console.log(response);
        });
```

When I call this function, it returns te restponse the the POST_ID. It's suposed to be successfull, but nothing is on my facebook fan page.

To give additional info, the access token cames from my currently signed in user of facebook, which is admin of the page.

What am I missing?

Comment: i assume it´s a user token, not a page token. check the user postings on your page, it may be in there.

Comment: Wow, yes, you're right! Well, this makes more sense. How do I obtain the page token? Because as soon as I use the app token, it gives me this error 

"(#200) User must have accepted TOS"

Comment: some resources about tokens: > http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/ > http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/